# Is there any way to modify the HTTP headers for IE6?

Tags: http-headers, browser

I need to be able to modify the HTTP headers for Internet Explorer for testing purposes.

Basically, I want to achieve the exact same thing that the [Modify Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/967) plugin for Firefox does.

Comment: All answers for this question are generalized and works for other versions.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could install [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and modify request headers with the [CustomRules.js](http://www.fiddlertool.com/Fiddler/dev/ScriptSamples.asp) file

Comment: The site has changed. Does Fiddler still have something to modify request headers? It is not obvious from the Fiddler application and I cannot find anything involving a CustomRules.js file.

Comment: @Joey Install Fiddler and install its [Syntax-Highlighting Add-Ons](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler/add-ons) then restart Fiddler and go to `Rules > Customize Rules...` then edit the file [as per the examples](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/KnowledgeBase/FiddlerScript/ModifyRequestOrResponse) and press `Save Script`. Now make a request and your new header(s) should show up.

Answer (score 22):

To modify the header with [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler):

1- Open Fiddler Web Debugger and in the menu toolbar go to `Rules`->`Customize Rules...` (shortcut is Ctrl + R). It opens the `CustomRules.js` file. Fiddler may suggest you to download Fiddler ScriptEditor but you can edit it with any text editor (I use notepad++)

2- Find `OnBeforeRequest(oSession: Session)` in the script file.

3- You can add a new header by adding `oSession.oRequest["NewHeaderName"] = "New header value";` to `OnBeforeRequest` function. Also, to remove a header, use `oSession.oResponse.headers.Remove("HeaderName");` function.

For more information see this [link](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/KnowledgeBase/FiddlerScript/ModifyRequestOrResponse)

Comment: This was a way more detailed answer than the accepted one. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You could use [Charles Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) to do all sorts of header rewriting.  It's a great tool.

Comment: Thanks! This also worked great, and is much nicer to use than Fiddler. Costs money though.

Comment: It still works without registration, just with nag screens and I think auto-shutdown after a period of time.  However, once you start using this tool you'll quickly realize it's well worth the small price.

Comment: If you actually think it's "much nicer", I'd very much like to hear why. Please email me using the Help / Send Feedback link in Fiddler.

Answer (score 3):

Proxomitron has the ability to modify headers for IE and its free

Comment: Great tip! It's a bit fiddly to set up, but the best feature is that it doesn't require admin privileges to install.