# modify request headers in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, http, http-headers, add-in

Is it possible to modify request headers sent by Internet Explorer. There are addins to do this for Mozilla Firefox. Is there a similar thing for IE.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I think fiddler will do that one for you.. I am not sure but give a try..

Comment: Yes Fiddler has Request Builder that can send HTTP requests with custom header but I want to include the headers in every request.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067781/is-there-any-way-to-modify-the-http-headers-for-ie6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install Fiddler and modify request headers with the `CustomRules.js` file.

For reference, visit [modify request headers in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067781/is-there-any-way-to-modify-the-http-headers-for-ie6)