# How to change the values for parameter Accept-Encoding in Internet Explorer 8?

Tags: asp.net, html, internet-explorer, browser

I'm doing some testing with `Content-Encoding` and `Accept-Encoding`.

I have some code on the server that send the encoding accordingly with browser value `Accept-Encoding`.

I would like to know if there is any option in IE to change the value for `Accept-Encoding` so that I can test my code on the Server?

Comment: Thanks bazmegakapa for your edit

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067781/is-there-any-way-to-modify-the-http-headers-for-ie6

Answer (score 0):

idk exactly what do you want but ie has encoding option when you right-click on page
you can use `UTF-8` if you have more than one language