# Is there any IE 11 extension to modify header same like mozilla with modify header?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, manual-testing

I would like to know more about IE 11 extension that can actually modify header manually. Basically I need to modify header and pass as "Referer" to spoof if we arrive on the webpage from that referer!

Much Appreciated
S

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to modify the HTTP headers for IE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067781/is-there-any-way-to-modify-the-http-headers-for-ie)

Answer (score 0):

You could install Fiddler and modify request headers with the CustomRules.js file

For reference - 
[Modify HTTP headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067781/is-there-any-way-to-modify-the-http-headers-for-ie6)

Also you can try this - Proxomitron

Comment: Proxomitron has the ability to modify headers for IE and its free